# PHP not compiling extensions / modules?

Tags: php, centos, centos6

I'm trying to install PHP 5.4 on a CentOS 6 x64 machine.

Currently I have 5.3.18 along with a few other things such as nginx/FPM installed from a repo, but I need 5.4 for a specific project.

I'm currently compiling with options:

```
./configure --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --cache-file=../config.cache --with-libdir=lib64 --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d --disable-debug --with-pic --disable-rpath --without-pear --with-bz2 --with-exec-dir=/usr/bin --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-xpm-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-t1lib=/usr --without-gdbm --with-gettext --with-iconv --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex=/usr --with-zlib --with-layout=GNU --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-magic-quotes --enable-sockets --with-kerberos --enable-ucd-snmp-hack --enable-shmop --enable-calendar --without-sqlite --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-xml --with-mhash --libdir=/usr/lib64/php --sysconfdir=/etc/php-fpm --enable-fpm --enable-mysqlnd --with-fpm-user=php-fpm --with-fpm-group=php-fpm --without-libedit --without-gd --without-pspell --without-sqlite3 --disable-dba --disable-dom --disable-pdo --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter --disable-phar --disable-fileinfo --disable-json --disable-wddx --disable-posix --disable-sysvmsg --disable-sysvshm --disable-sysvsem --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

I'm doing `make && make install` and whilst the install appears to be successful, PHP doesn't seem to be compiling the extensions into the extensions directly `/usr/lib64/php/20100525`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why do you do this --disable-pdo and then do this --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of compiling it by hand, consider installing packages from [Remi's repository](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en).  Remi is the PHP maintainer for Fedora, the distro that drives RHEL, and in turn CentOS.

The "remi-test" repo currently has 5.4.9 available for CentOS [5.x](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/test/x86_64/repoview/) and [6.x](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/test/x86_64/repoview/).

Do use the repo with care.  It will also want to update MySQL, and that *could* have undesired side-effects.  The repo also requires [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), but you should have it available anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Which extensions are you looking for? As far I as I can see you built PHP statically. You have to use --enabled-shared in order to get shared extensions then they will go in `/usr/{PREFIX}/php/extensions/{your-build}/` ... see http://php.net/configure.about